# prelaunchr (ruby on rails) how to turn off openssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to deploy Prelaunchr (https://github.com/harrystech/prelaunchr) and I have a problem with mailing. When delayed_job tries to send mail it returns an error "hostname does not match the server certificate" (full error: http://pastebin.com/eHp1pTKk). How can I turn off validation and just make email send without any ssl or anything? I need to finish it in next 24h so I don't want it fancy, I need it working.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more than 24 hours, but here's a related question which should point you in the right direction:

[OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: hostname does not match the server certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190868/opensslsslsslerror-hostname-does-not-match-the-server-certificate)